# Programming a sum function in python?

Tags: python

how to sum numbers attached to words in a text file(not separate them into digits) in python? (example: "a23 B55" - answer = 78)
thats what i did but its not quite right:

```
def rixum(file_name):
f = open(file_name,'r')
line = f.readline()
temp = line.split()
res = []
for word in temp:
    i = 0
    while i < len(word)-1:
        if word[i].isdigit():
            res.append(int(word[i:]))
print(sum(res))
f.close()
return sum(res)
```

Comment: In what way is "its not quite right"?

Comment: you are using a while loop but `i` is never changed

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import re
string = 'F43 n90 i625'

def summ_numbers(string):
    return sum([int(num) for num in re.findall('\d+', string)])

print(summ_numbers(string))
```

Output:

```
758
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to build a list - you can simply accumulate the values as you go along (line by line):

```
def rixum(filename):
    with open(filename) as data:
        for line in data:
            total = 0
            for token in line.split():
                for i, c in enumerate(token):
                    if c.isdigit():
                        total += int(token[i:])
                        break
            print(total)
```